# Error Creating sheet in workspace from template using API

Tags: smartsheet-api-2.0

I have an automated system that uses python code to create new sheets in workspaces and it has been operational since 2021/10/13. This morning, the same code generates an error "errorCode": 1006. I have confiemd that there have been no changes to persmisions for the workspace and the template however the following code generates this error:

```
response = SMARTSHEET_CLIENT.Workspaces.create_sheet_in_workspace_from_template(
                            1728912880363396,  # NVO COURSE STUDENT CONTROL Workspace
                            smartsheet.models.Sheet({
                                'name': f'{actionSheetFFprefix} CONTROL SHEET',
                                'from_id': 8237502436796292
                            }),
                            ['attachments', 'cellLinks', 'data', 'discussions', 'forms', 'rules', 'ruleRecipients']
                        )
```

A curl request for the list of templates, and workspaces reveals that the SS_TEMPLATE_ID still exists and the Bearer ID used is that of the owner/admin of the template and the workpace.

```
{
    "id": 8237502436796292,
    "name": "TEMPLATE of CONTROL SHEET V10.2",
    "accessLevel": "OWNER"
  }
```

AND

```
"id": 1728912880363396,
  "name": "NVO COURSE STUDENT CONTROL",
  "accessLevel": "ADMIN",
  "permalink": "https://app.smartsheet.com/workspaces/8354Qpcmw2p2G59MR59mq3cgmRPFPRm2q8pmfgC1",
  "sheets": [{....
```

What could have changed to suddenly cause this issue when it's been working for over 2 years?

I tried to run the api reuest from a curl tool to check for the specific workpace and for the specific template.

I expected to get results back for both but only the workspace returns a value as expected, and the template curl request returns "errorCode": 1006.

I have also gone into the front end to comfirm the items i'm looking for exists:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM0d1.png)

Comment: While tinkering further i found that removing the "include" list of elements both when using curl or the sdk results in a successful repsonse from the API. However the created sheet doesn't then have the data formating and prepopulated data from the template. Again this was working for over two years and has just stopped working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a known issue that SMARTSHEET tech support are working on. to quote the response to a case no. I raised:

"After testing this behavior, this looks like the "data" parameter is causing the error message, as it works successfully when not including "data". We have engaged our engineering team and they are investigating and working on a fix. We currently don't have a timeline on a resolution, but we understand there are multiple users are affected, so this will be resolved as soon as possible. We appreciate your patience! "